# Update() function in the Laravel Resource Controller is not working

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm trying to use the update() function to update the selected user but when I click submit, it just goes back to index (as it should) but updates nothing. Following is my code:

**StudentController** (Resource Controller):

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::all();
        return view ('main',compact('students'));
    }
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view ('create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Student::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('main.index')->with('create','Student has been added successfully!');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id, Student $student)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    return view ('edit',compact('student'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    $student->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('main.index')->with('update','Student has been updated!');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

**Main.blade.php** (Index):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="py-4">
            @if (Session::has('create'))
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    {{ Session::get('create') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            @if (Session::has('update'))
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    {{ Session::get('update') }}
                </div>
            @endif
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Students
                {{ link_to_route('main.create','Add Student','',['class'=>'btn btn-success float-right']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($students as $student)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $student->gender }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $student->address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $student->class }}</td>
                    <td>{{ link_to_route('main.edit','Edit',[$student->id],['class'=> 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit.blade.php** (Model):

```
{!! Form::model($student,array('route'=>['main.update',$student->id],'method'=>'PUT')) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Add Student Name']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::select('gender', [
                         'Male' => 'Male',
                         'Female' => 'Female'],
                          null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Choose Gender']); !!}
                          </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::text('address',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Add Student Address']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                   {!! Form::select('class', [
                    'A' => 'A',
                    'B' => 'B',
                    'C' => 'C',
                    'D' => 'D',],
                     null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Choose Class']); !!}
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group py-4">
                        {!! Form::submit('Edit',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-block']) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Student.php** (Model):

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','gender','address','class'];
}
```

My create.blade.php is exactly the same as my edit.blade.php, the only changes are in the Form::open() line. And the edit page even displays my old data on the input fields but when I make a change & click Update, it just doesn't update anything in the database or the index page - so what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance and please feel free to ask if any more code is required for you guys to crack this one.

Comment: Don't you get any errors on update?

Comment: show us the output of dd($request->all()); from your update()  function

Comment: What are you getting when  you `dd($student)` ?

Comment: Does the update alert get displayed? Try to dd($student->getAttributes()) before and after updating the model to see if it changes.

Comment: When I do this in update():

`dd($student->getAttributes());
        $student->update($request->all());
        dd($student->getAttributes());
        return redirect()->route('main.index')->with('update','Student has been updated!');`

It returns me an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try..

```
   public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {
    $student =  Student::find($id);
    $student->name = $request->input('name');
    $student->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $student->address = $request->input('address');
    $student->class = $request->input('class');
    $student->save();
    return redirect()->route('main.index')->with('update','Student has been updated!');
    }
```

Comment: @VenoM you should use `only(['name', 'gender', 'address', 'class'])` instead of getting each value and your type hinting was right but you just removed it :( !

Answer (score 5):

Try this one out:

```
public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $student->fill($input)->save();

 return redirect()->route('main.index')->with('update','Student has been updated!');
}
```

Comment: Why did you replace `->update()` with `fill()->save()`. It does absolutely the same but longer and not so easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

In your `edit.blade.php`,

```
{!! Form::submit('route_to_update()',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-block']) !!}
```

change "Edit" 
And you can check your route by in your console like "`php artisan  route:list`"

and check your route is reached 
by `var_damp()` or `var_export()` or `dd()`in your student controller update function

Answer (score 1):

`request()->all()` contains method and token information. Can you maybe pass it through a validator?

```
$validated = request()->validate([
'name' => 'required',
'address' => '',
..
]);
$student->update($validated);
```